# Write a line of text just on the very bottom of the pages

Tags: border, footer

I wish to write a line of (small size) text at the very lower border of the page (below the footer).
Is it even possible? How?

I need it for a  \documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article},  ~700 pages document.

I tried `\renewcommand{\turnthepage}{\footnotesize{My version of \today{,} \currenttime{.}}}`, but it does not seem to go below the footer space.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  \AddToHook{shipout/background}{...} will run on every page.  The only question is whether to use tikzpagenodes or calculate the x,y coordinates yourself.

Comment: How do I accept two answers? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One advantage of the `xcoffin` package is that allows to put stuff anywhere in the page, even outside the margins, footer, heads, etc.

You put the content in a box (`\Timex`) and join to an empty box (`\Frame`), with appropriate offsets. The `\Typeset` will put the assembly in the current insertion point so it has to be shifted to the left and down. There are two values I added (1ex and 7ex) that might need to be adjusted if the font is changed. The same if you decided to use the `geometry` package.

The package `atbegshi` will then put the sentence in every page, in the lower left corner.

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[us,12hr]{datetime} 

\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%   
\TypesetCoffin\Framex}}

\NewCoffin\Framex
\NewCoffin\Timex
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Timex{\footnotesize{My version of \today{,} \currenttime{.}}}

\begin{document}    
\JoinCoffins*\Framex[l,b]\Timex[l,b](-\oddsidemargin-1in +7ex,\topmargin+\topskip+\headheight+\headsep-\paperheight+1ex) % X Y offsets

1. \kant[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: out]

Comment: It works, thanks so much.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two options: Using [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) or the default LaTeX hooks.

- `eso-pic`'s `\AddToShipoutPictureForeground`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{lipsum,datetime2}

  \usepackage{eso-pic}
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
      \raisebox{.5\baselineskip}
        {\hspace{.5\baselineskip}\footnotesize My version of \DTMtoday, \DTMcurrenttime.}%
    }%
  }

  \begin{document}

  \sloppy\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

  \end{document}
  ```
- LaTeX's shipout hooks: `\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}`

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage{lipsum,datetime2}

  \AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
    \put(.5\baselineskip,-\paperheight+.5\baselineskip)
      {\footnotesize My version of \DTMtoday, \DTMcurrenttime.}
  }

  \begin{document}

  \sloppy\lipsum[1-50]\lipsum[1-50]

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: The first solution works fine. Thanks a lot. The second on returns a number of errors (even with your MWE).

Comment: @mario: It requires an up-to-date LaTeX. There was an Oct 2020 release that includes the new hook management. See [LaTeX News Issue 32](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews32.pdf).

Comment: Ok, I'll check. On my Fedora 32 machine, I use to update by just `dnf update texlive`. Your first solution works fine.